# JerseyTest NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, junit, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I am receiving the following stack trace after trying to run any test on jersey (this happen only on junit tests):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:337)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:140)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:82)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:66)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.create(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:609)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

my maven dependencies look like :

```
  <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <version.jdk>1.7</version.jdk>
 <version.mvn.compiler>3.2</version.mvn.compiler>
 <version.mvn.war.plugin>2.6</version.mvn.war.plugin>
 <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
 <version.jersey>2.22.2</version.jersey>
 <version.servlet.api>3.0.1</version.servlet.api>
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>          
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

my base test class looks like :

```
public class BaseResourceTest extends JerseyTest{
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
    rc.packages("com.someName.jaxrs.resource");
    AbstractBinder binder = new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindFactory(MockDataServiceFactory.class).to(DataService.class);
        }
    };
    rc.register(binder);
    rc.register(AuthenticationFilter.class);
    rc.register(PermissionFilter.class);
    return rc;
    }
 }
```

and my testing class looks like this:

```
public class SomeResourceTests extends BaseResourceTest{
     @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        System.out.println("test"); // the exception occures in the base class so this print doesn't happen
    }
}
```

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: I can tell you from the information you've provided, the problem is not reproducible. The problem is as @Hermant mentions, but nothing in what you've provided would cause this. Maybe try a clean and build. Maybe you had the conflicting dependencies earlier, removed it and never cleaned, I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

This comes due to jar conflicts means some of your classes are present in different jar but in same package.
As you facing this problem only in test cases so scan your jars once again.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered with same problem earlier. There may be two dependency of javax.ws.rs-api with different version in your classpath. One dependency you have included explicitly. Other one will be included transitively from other dependencies. 
Just go into  dependency heirarchy (in eclipse) of your pom.XML. Find out the artifact which includes javax.WS.rs-api dependency and add exclusion to it in your dependency.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assist but it didn't work, I added an exclusion tag for every item except the javax.ws.rs dependency itself and I am still receiving the same error